# How to use Oauth2.0 without server side rendering CORS issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm using a React SPA which is required to login via an Oauth2.0-compliant authorization server (using `https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider`). My authorization server is just an api (no SSR). I've also implemented a separate React SPA for the front end. So, when the server responds with the authorization code, and a `302` redirect, the browser prevents the SPA from redirecting to another SPA which is not able (as far as I'm aware) to respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and allow the CORS request.

It seems like Oauth2.0 was not designed to be used with SPA's, but I'd be surprised if all authorization servers are server-side rendered. Is there a workaround for this (without breaking compliance or switching to SSR)?

Comment: Did you find something about it? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I switched to SSR because it seems to be too much against the grain it wasn’t worth it.